# @HostListener not working in a proper way

Tags: angular, event-listener

i created a drag event listener using the HostListener to check whether the element is being dragged inside the browser window or outside of it , so when the element is dragged inside the browser window it shows me a div " drop zone "  written inside of it drop your files here and when i leave the browser window i want that div to disappear.

my 2 event listeners :

```
displayDropZone: boolean = false;

  @HostListener('window:dragenter', ['$event'])
  onDragEnter() {
   console.log(" DRAG ENTER")
   this.displayDropZone = true;
 }

  @HostListener('window:dragleave', ['$event'])
   onDragLeave() {
    console.log(" DRAG LEFT")
    this.displayDropZone = false;
 }
```

the div to be displayed depending on the drag event :

```
           <div *ngIf="displayDropZone" style="background-color: black;" id="dropzone" 
                  (dragover)="false"
                (dragend)="false" (drop)="handleDrop($event)">
                <p style="margin: 16%; text-align: center"> <strong>Drop Your Images Here</strong> 
           </p>
            </div>
```

so the problem is that the div keeps being displayed and hidden at the same time and the drag event is not working in the correct way because when the dragged element is still in the browser window it says DRAG LEFT which i don't know why it's happening even though i didn't leave the browser window

Comment: it should be (dragend), or (dragleave) event ?

Comment: @onik dragleave to check if the element left the browser to hide the div just like facebook you can try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the window drag leave event is called if you hover an item to the displayDropZone element, so you need to add the condition on dragleave event

```
  @HostListener("window:dragleave", ["$event"])
  onDragLeave(e) {
    if (!e.fromElement) {  // this will ensure that you are not in the browser anymore
      console.log(" DRAG LEFT");
      this.displayDropZone = false;
    }
  }
```